# Does Nginx has reponse phase?

Tags: http, nginx, response

Nginx has 11 HTTP phases as stated on the official doc: http://nginx.org/en/docs/dev/development_guide.html#http_phases.

The last two phases are as follows.

1. `NGX_HTTP_CONTENT_PHASE` generate response (e.g. receiving from upstream).
2. `NGX_HTTP_LOG_PHASE` print request to `access.log`.

I have two questions.

1. After generating response, Nginx seems does not have a “Response Phase”. Why?
2. Since there is not a response phase, does Nginx print an access log after or before the response is sent to client?

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to answer my own question.

1. After generating response, Nginx seems does not have a “Response Phase”. Why?

   There is not a "Response Phase". The response sending is implicitly embraced in the "Content Phase".
2. Since there is not a response phase, does Nginx print an access log after or before the response is sent to client?

   Ningx writes access log after response is sent to client, which can be verified by [access log_format](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html#log_format). In the access log, we can log `$bytes_sent` and `$request_time`. These two values are only available after response is completely sent to client.